# proguard multiple injars to multiple outjars: The output jar must have a filter, or all subsequent output jars will be empty

Tags: filter, proguard

How to proguard multiple jars, and write out to different jars. Each jar has java classes and resources.

```
-injars foo.jar
-injars bar.jar

-outjars foo1.jar
-outjars bar1.jar
```

Error:

```
 The output jar must have a filter, or all subsequent output jars will be empty.
```

How to specify filter? how to specify one to one mapping? i.e.

```
foo.jar -> foo1.jar
bar.jar -> bar1.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `outjars` rule will output all classes read from the `injars` rules before it (position is important). So if you want to output multiple jars to multiple outputs you can do the following:

```
-injars foo.jar
-outjars foo1.jar

-injars bar.jar
-outjars bar1.jar
```

All classes from foo.jar will end up in foo1.jar and all classes from bar.jar will go into bar1.jar (of course unless they are shrunk or optimized).

Edit: the other solution would include a filter like this:

```
-injars foo.jar
-injars bar.jar
-outjars foo1.jar(com/foo/**)
-outjars bar1.jar(com/bar/**)
```

Only classes that match the filter will end up in the respective `outjar`, but you need to be careful with the filter to include everything that is inside `foo.jar`.